# how to delete duplicate entry of a word

Tags: c#

I would like to delete the second entry of a word, for example if i'll find in a text:

```
Alex Alex
```

one of the entries should be deleted.

Comment: Is this string a series of words separated by spaces? Is punctuation a factor? Should they be deleted if it's in twice (ie "Alex Jon Alex") or only if they're successive?

Comment: yes, it should also delete any duplicates in the text, for example:

Alex is going to buy some milk and Alex has a cat...bla bla

Answer (score 2):

Use following regex

```
(\b\S+\b)(?=.*\1)
```

and replace with `$1`

This uses [back reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx) feature or regex.

Comment: Do i have to use a Regex.Replace method?

Comment: Yes. Notice there was a mistake not \1 but $1

Comment: Seems like i'm getting an error

    
           if (Regex.Replace(cuvant, "^(\b\\S+\b)(?=.*$1)$"))

               returnVer = "Duplicate deleted";

Comment: u need to escape \ while putting to C# string try Regex.Replace(cuvant, "^(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\1)","$1");

Comment: Can not convert type "string" to "bool", any ideas?

Comment: Regex.Replace returns resulting string after replacing so you can not put it this way into if

Comment: Then how? :) i'm a begginer

Answer (score 2):

I will not do this with regex.

I would do it this way:

```
private string RemoveDuplicateWord(string input)
    {
        string[] words = input.Split(' ');
        var listOfWords = new List<string>();

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (!listOfWords.Contains(word))
                listOfWords.Add(word);
        }

        var arrayString = listOfWords.ToArray();

        return string.Join(" ", arrayString);
    }
```